# Spring Boot e Hibernate - problemas para subir aplicação e mapear classes em entidades

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

o lance é o seguinte,  criei uma página usando Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, Hibernate e MySql para cadastro de estacionamentos e veículos mas estou muito perdido em relação ao mapeamento das entidades e configurações que devo fazer e etc. A parte de cadastro de estacionamentos funcionou perfeitamente, mas estou tendo problemas para implementar a parte de cadastro de veículos, dentro dos estacionamentos. Não sei se devo ter os atributos da classe iguais as colunas que tenho no banco e não sei como resolver a questão das chaves estrangeiras no meu banco e as devidas anotações nas classes. Eu criei as seguintes tabelas para o sistema direto no banco de dados.

- Empresa: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKViW.jpg
- Veiculo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdt0L.jpg

E as minhas classes do modelo estão assim

Empresa:

```
package com.codejava.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Empresa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_empresa;
    private String nome;
    private String cnpj;
    private String endereco;
    private String telefone;
    private int qtd_carros;
    private int qtd_motos;
    private List<Veiculo> veiculos;


    public Empresa() {

    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Veiculo.class, mappedBy="empresa")
    public List<Veiculo> getVeiculos() {
        return veiculos;
    }


   /*getters e setters*/

}
```

e

Veiculo:

```
package com.codejava.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Veiculo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_veiculo;
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    private String cor;
    private String placa;
    private TipoVeiculo tipo;
    private Empresa empresa;

    public Veiculo() {

    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_empresa")
    public Empresa getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }

    /*
   getters e setters
*/
}
```

Estou tendo a seguinte mensagem de erro ao tentar rodar a aplicação:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-05-06 19:15:06.876 ERROR 12104 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: empresa, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(veiculos)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.codejava.GerenciadorEstacionamentoApplication.main(GerenciadorEstacionamentoApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: empresa, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(veiculos)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: empresa, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(veiculos)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:454) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:421) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:489) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:878) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score -2):

o erro se encontra nessa parte: Traduzido:

```
A exceção aninhada é org.hibernate.MappingException: não foi possível determinar o tipo para: java.util.List, na tabela: empresa, para colunas: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column (veiculos)]
```

Aqui está alguém que passou por um problema semelhante:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-at